# Installing ODT giving Oracle Client Error [INS-50016]

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, odac, oracleclient, odt

I am trying to install **ODT with ODAC** in order to use Oracle with Entity Framework 
it gives me the error

> [INS-50016] Please install in a Regular Client Home, a new Oracle Home or an existing ODAC Home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear. You have to install also an Oracle Client (e.g. the Instant Client) - unless you use the Oracle Data Provider for .NET **Managed** Driver.

In case you have an Oracle Client already installed it might be the wrong version. Version of Oracle Client and Oracle Data Provider have to match **exactly!**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ODAC, try the NuGet package.  [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramewor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/)k